# Reference variable to an instance member

Tags: c#, reference

I have this data class:

```
class MyClass
{
    Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
    Foo Foo3 { get; set; }
    Foo Foo4 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, somewhere else in my program, I have this function:

```
void ModifyMyClass(MyClass myClassInstance)
{
    var rightFooToModify = myclassInstance.Foo1;

    rightFooToModify = new Foo();  // Here, my intention is to
                                   // modify MyClass, not just the
                                   // local variable 'rightFooToModify'
}
```

I need to be able to choose one of Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 (depending on some conditions) and then set it to a new Foo object.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Are there some kind of reference variable that I can use for this in C#?

**EDIT:**

I could use (and it is actually what I use right now):

```
myClassInstance.Foo1 = new Foo();
```

But, ModifyMyClass() is actually a bit more complicated, for example:

```
void ModifyMyClass(MyClass myClassInstance)
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        var rightFooToModify = myClassInstance.Foo1
        // ... Do some computation with rightFooToModify
        myClassInstance.Foo1 = new Foo(/* some parameters */);
    }
    else if (someOtherCondition)
    {
        // The exact same code as the if above , but with
        // myClassInstance.Foo2 instance.
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid duplicating the code in the `if` block in all the following `else if`. That is why I would like to just use `var rightFooToModify = myClassInstance.Foo1` at the start of the method and not duplicate the code needlessly in mutliple `if`s.

Comment: `myclassInstance.Foo1 = new Foo()`

Comment: This is what I do. I edited my question to show why I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Why don't you extract a selector method which depending on your condition just give the right instance of `Foo` to your `ModifyMyClass` method. That would save some duplication. You can then refactor more depending on what your codebase looks like (e.g. if all those Foo instances are slightly different, you can try to either set up a class hierarchy or maybe use generics). But I would say separating the selector method is the start.

Comment: I think the real issue (which causes the duplication) is more the assignment part. Even with a selector, if I want to assign to the instance, I will have to use the name `myClassInstance.Foo1 = ...` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it like this

When you assign your property to a local variable,

```
var rightFooToModify = myclassInstance.Foo1;
```

all you are doing is writing a post-it-Note with the location of some memory on.

If someone gives you another post-it-note with some more, replacing the original one

```
rightFooToModify = new Foo();
```

It doesn't change the original memory, its still there, nothing happened.

This is how pointers/references work. They point/reference a location in memory, you can copy a reference yet overwriting that reference doesn't do anything to the original memory location, you just have a new post-it-note pointing to somewhere else.

However, now for a really contrived example of a way to overcome this with [`ref return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values) and [`ref Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals)

> ***Disclaimer***, i don't really advocate doing this in your situation, however for sheer academic purposes lets look at this language
>   feature

**Given**

```
public class MyClass
{
   private Foo _foo1;

   public Foo Foo1
   {
      get => _foo1;
      set => _foo1 = value;
   }

   public ref Foo ModifyMyClass()
   {
      return ref _foo1;
   }
}
```

**Example**

```
// create class
var someClass = new MyClass();

// create some memory for it
someClass.Foo1 = new Foo();
someClass.Foo1.SomeValue = "test";

// copy the reference to it
var copy = someClass.Foo1; 

// overwrite it
copy = new Foo();
copy.SomeValue = "test2";

// oh nossssssssss!!!! is didn't change!!
Console.WriteLine(someClass.Foo1.SomeValue);


//enter ref local
ref var  actualLocation = ref someClass.ModifyMyClass();

// create some memory
actualLocation = new Foo();
actualLocation.SomeValue = "test3";

// omg it worked!!!!
Console.WriteLine(someClass.Foo1.SomeValue);
```

**Output**

```
test
test3
```

And yet another bizarre and weird usage of ref

```
someClass.ModifyMyClass() = new Foo();
someClass.ModifyMyClass().SomeValue = "I hope i never see this in my code base";
Console.WriteLine(someClass.Foo1.SomeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of any help, but you can have a method returning the correct setter of type `Action<MyClass, Foo>` , i.e.

```
Action<MyClass, Foo> GetFooSetter()
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        return (myClass, foo) => myClass.Foo1 = foo;
    }
    else if (someOtherCondition)
    {
        return (myClass, foo) => myClass.Foo2 = foo;
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
GetFooSetter()(myClassInstance, new Foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

The use case is not so clear, so I will suggest two options:

1. If `Foo` is not immutable, then just modify it's values instead of assigning it to a new instance. You can even add a copy function to copy values from another `Foo`:

   ```
   Foo fooToChange = myClassInstance.Foo1;
   fooToChange.CopyFrom(new Foo());
   ```
2. Refactor to hold the Foos in an array, then you can ask for it and assign with an index:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
       public Foo[] Foos = new Foo[4];
   }

   int fooToChange = 3;
   myClassInstance.Foos[3] = new Foo();
   ```